# Upload .doc to blog

Tags: images, uploads

All my blog contents are well prepared in MS Word. Some contents have image flow chart.

On copying the contents from Word doc, i am not able to copy the Images.

How should i copy both contents and images from word doc to the Blog?

Or

Is there any way to upload each doc file which will directly extract the contents including images from Word doc to the Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way would be to use [Windows Live Writer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/essentials-other-programs?T1=t5).  It's a Microsoft product that's part of the [Windows Live Essentials suite](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/essentials-other-programs).

This program allows you to copy-paste content from a Word document, or just build the post out as you would in Word.  But the advantage is that it can also talk directly to your WordPress site using [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).

This means you can write your post locally, format images locally, and get everything set up locally *just as you would in Word*.  Then you hit publish, and Writer will push the content *and your images* to your site.

Comment: Thank you. I am installing Windows Live Writer. What does your second line do ? You said some thing about XML-RPC

Comment: XML-RPC is the way Writer talks to your site.  You don't need to understand it to use it, you just need to make sure it's turned on for your site.  Go to Settings > Writing and check the box next to "Enable the WordPress, Movable Type, MetaWeblog and Blogger XML-RPC publishing protocols." under Remote Publishing. Then follow the instructions that Writer gives you to connect to the site.

Comment: I am facing a new issue. I tried to publish the Word - .doc to Wordpress. I am getting an error message as " Word cannot publish the pictures in this post. The most likely cause of this problem is that you do not  have enough storage space. Contact your provider and try again, or choose a different picture provider.

Comment: Publishing from Word or from Windows Live Writer?

Comment: I have installed Windows Live Writer, But i am publishing from Word

Comment: I dont know, where this Windows Live Writer is located

Comment: It's located wherever you installed it. If you're running Windows 7, just typing "Writer" in the "Search Programs and Files" field of the start menu should locate it.

Comment: I just did a test, using Word, from my machine. I can verify that this works at least with Word 2007 and the latest version of Windows Live Writer - both against the latest version of WordPress. If you're having issues with images, they're probably too large ... but this is a support issue (separate from this question) and should be taken to the [support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/).

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is a **Content Management System** that is designed for content to be created **within the application itself**; it is *not* a *Microsoft document conversion system*.

I recommend that, if you intend to publish your content via a content management system such as WordPress, you *get **out** of the habit of developing your content in non-CMS applications*, and instead *get **in** the habit of creating your content within your CMS*.

WordPress supports rich-text editing, which precludes the need to pre-format your text in a word processor. WordPress also supports attachment/insertion of images and other types of embedded content. If need to include a flow chart, create it in Visio (or your app of choice), save it as an image, and upload/attach it via the in-post media manager.

Comment: I agree with you to an extent. But, we got all our contents in a doc file. We have around 50 doc files. Each file has some image flow chart on it.